# How can I use "ease" for smoother dragging?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have dragging mc called "box" but the dragging  is not smooth at all.

So how can I make it smoother by using "ease" var.

I'm trying to use "/ease" anywhere but not work.

```
var topY:int = stage.stageHeight - box.height;
var botY:int = 0;


box.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onDown);
box.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onUp);
var constrainY:Rectangle = new Rectangle(box.x, topY ,0, box.y+ (box.height-stage.stageHeight)  );
var dragxy:String = "";
function onDown(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    dragxy = mouseX + "_" + mouseY;
    e.currentTarget.startDrag(false, constrainY);
    removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onDown);
    addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onUp);
}
function onUp(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    e.currentTarget.stopDrag();
    addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onDown);
    removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onUp);
}
```

Comment: it's unclear what you are asking for help with.  Do you want the box to follow the mouse but trail behind it and ease into its final position?  Or do you want the box to just have a higher frame rate so that it doesn't look so choppy?  Also, you say you want to use the var ease... that's not a thing, so you'll have to explain better what you are trying to do.  You probably are wanting the box to follow the mouse with an "ease in" animation, in which case `startDrag` is the wrong method.  You need to write an easing function or use one of the many libraries available online.

Answer (score 0):

a simple example of an easing function would be:

```
private function easeTo(obj:MovieClip,currentGoalx:Number,currentGoaly:Number,easeFac:Number):void{
    obj.x += (currentGoalx-obj.x)/easeFac;
    obj.y += (currentGoaly-obj.y)/easeFac;
}
```

first you will need a timer or enter frame loop such as this added to the stage:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,enterFrame);
```

then in your enterFrame function do this:

```
private function enterFrame(e:Event):void{
    easeTo(box,stage.mouseX,stage.mouseY,3);
}
```

an easeFac of 3 is a slower and smoother ease-in than an easeFac of 2, and 4 is even smoother and buttery-er.

or something like that.  The idea is that the obj goes half the distance to the goal on each function call.  So if this function is getting called on every frame, you'll get a smooth "ease in" effect.  If you set currentGoal as the mouse position, then the obj will follow the mouse wherever it goes, but not in a 1:1 matching, rather it will trail behind and smoothly catch up.

Comment: Hello Neal Davis, how can I implement into my code?

Comment: And now I've added the bit about the frame event in case you didn't know how to make a frame event listener

Comment: It said undefined property currentGoal.

Comment: Sorry. Fixed it. Should be currentGoaly and currentGoalx